# FlinkKafkaConsumer: Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The request timed out

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Getting "org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The request timed out" in Flink kafka consumer.

2022-06-06 08:57:24,044 WARN  org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.KafkaFetcher  - Committing offsets to Kafka failed. This does not compromise Flink's checkpoints.
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RetriableCommitFailedException: Offset commit failed with a retriable exception. You should retry committing the latest consumed offsets.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The request timed out.

Actually I am using Filink Kafka consumer with Kafka Connector
org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer for topic "xyz". We pushed the 6 Millions of messages to topic.

FlinkKafkaConsumer able to consume the messages and processing fine. But in the TaskManager logs, we are seeing the below warning.

FlinkKafkaConsumer: Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The request timed out

Please let me know. if any one come across the above issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There's not really enough details here. Kafka network exceptions aren't really related to Flink, and you can see them under various situations, including general misconfiguration, the Kafka brokers / a network switch dying, etc.

Comment: Can you let us know what version of Flink you're using, and what version of the `flink-connector-kafka` library you're using. You mention you're using the FlinkKafkaConsumer, and that class has been marked for deprecation with version 1.14. The unified source and sink code has a KafkaSource class that should be used.